# Why super classes generic type not erased/casted

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class A<T>{
T t;

public T getValue(){
    return t;
}

class B<S extends Number> extends A<String>{

//some code here..
}

B b = new B<Integer>();
String name = b.getValue() // This throws compilation error
```

whereas the following works:

```
B<Integer> b = new B<Integer>();
String name = b.getValue() // This works...!
```

So my questions are:

1. Do I have to give declare all the generics type involved? (Even though Class A's generic type was declared in Class B.)
2. Or, am I missing something basically?

Comment: You've omitted the crucial part, which is the declaration of `B.getValue()`.

Comment: Between, why should I override the method in B, when I don't want to change any behavior of getValue()? Also, the A's type has been declared as Long in B, to erase it.

Comment: @JimGarrison but the decleration for `getValue` is in the class `A`

Comment: I have edited the question, as the earlier one causes confusions between Number and Long, its better now to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [JLS 4.8 Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> a raw type is defined to be [...] the reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.
>
> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of its parameterized invocations.

In other words, when you use `B` without `<>`, it becomes a raw type, basically erasing *all* generics, all the way up all base classes and interfaces, i.e. is becomes as if `A` and `B` weren't generic:

```
class A {
    Object t;
    public Object getValue() {
        return t;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    //some code here..
}
```

Which is why `String name = b.getValue()` fails, because `getValue()` is now returning an `Object`.

---

Note the following comment in the JLS:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. **The use of raw types** in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language **is strongly discouraged**. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

In short, **DON'T**. Fix your code to not use raw types.

You can however shorten the right-hand side as follows:

```
B<Integer> b = new B<>();
```

Answer (score -1):

The generic value of class B simply has no link with the one from class A.

The method T getValue() of a A(Long) will be Long getValue(), disregarding any genericity on the wrapping class.

If you want an Integer getValue() then simply go for

```
class B extends A<Integer> {}
```

EDIT : you change your question, lets change the response :)

B is considered as B (S extends Number, T) (because it extends A).
If you store a variable as a raw type B, then its is implicitly B(Object, Object), even if declared properly.

Make test with a List

```
List l = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = l.get(0);
```

You will end with the same issue.

Comment: I have edited the question, as the earlier one causes confusions between Number and Long, its better now to understand what I mean.

Comment: I think OP rather wants to know , even though the generic `S` is unrelated to the class `A`, and whilst `getValue` should already return a `Long` due to the decleration of the class `B`, why he has to provide the generic `S` while defining the variable in order for `B` to return a `Long` for `A#getValue`, whilst without it it returns an `Object`.